# Find next event

Tags: entries, datetime, events

I'm trying to find the next event after today (now) from a series of entries. This code however outputs all upcoming events after today but I'm just looking for the first (next) event.

Any help is appreciated

```
{% set nextEvent =  craft.events.events.find() %}
{% for entry in nextEvent %}
    {% if entry.startDate > now %}
    <span class="text-primary">{{ entry.title }}</span><br>
    {{ entry.startDate|date('d F Y ') }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Is this a plugin you're using or is `craft.events.events.find()` a typo in your question?

Comment: The find() is a typo. I'm using the Craft events plugin for this.

Answer (score 3):

When you are setting `nextEvent`, you can limit only events that are upcoming and only output the first result you get back like so:

```
.startDate('>= ' ~ now).first()
```

So you can take that and update your code like so:

```
{% set nextEvent = craft.entries.section('events').order('startDate').startDate('>= ' ~ now).first() %}

{% if nextEvent %}
    foo
{% endif %}
```

I have assumed you have a section called 'Event's until we get some clarification as to what `craft.events.events` is.

Comment: That was fast enough, Jamie! Congrats. ;) I'd suggest to use `first` method instead of setting a limit, though.

Comment: The code won't work as I'm using the Craft events plugin. {% set nextEvent = craft.entries.events.order('startDate').startDate('>= ' ~ now).limit(1) %} is trowing in an SQL state error (column not found)

Comment: @RobbiePost Hi Robbie, please have a look at the answer posted by carlcs. The code I supplied will work, but you will need to make some adjustments to how you handle events, as that plugin shouldn't be used in production sites.

Answer (score 2):

P&T's events plugin available on GitHub http://github.com/pixelandtonic/Events is actually not meant to be used at all. It was just a demo to show the potential of custom element types!

I'd suggest to use a channel section for your events, and with the code Jamie provided you're already done figuring out how to find your "next event"! You could also collect events with a matrix field, if you have a need for an extra level of hierarchy and if that's still not enough you could have your events in a table in that matrix (using the ["Super Table"](https://github.com/engram-design/SuperTable) plugin).

There's also two other plugins: ["Events"](https://github.com/tippingmedia/craft.events) and ["Calendar"](http://michaelrog.com/craft/calendars/introduction), but I'm not sure if they are still under development and I'd probably stick to core Craft features (channels / matrix) for now.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying carlcs. I agree, the P&T plugin is a no-go and a channel would be the best option for this.

Comment: For me events plugin was a quick and simple solution for a simple project. I solved the issue by hiding the generated list in HTML and only showing the first-child. Thanks for the suggestions

Comment: There's a better way to do this, @Robbie. I just posted another answer, but please do me a favor and don't accept it. Using P&T plugin is indeed a no-go ...

Comment: The breakloop suggestion did the job and solved the issue. It's clear now that the P&T events plugin is not the way to go

Answer (score 2):

To break a for loop you could have a variable and check against its value in your loop:

```
{% set breakLoop = false %}

{% for entry in nextEvent %}

    {% if (entry.startDate > now) and (breakLoop == false) %}
        {{ entry.startDate }}
        {% set breakLoop = true %}
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Or – if you have a need to break loops more often – use the plugin ["Break and Continue"](https://github.com/marionnewlevant/craft-mnbreakandcontinue), that gives you a Twig tag for this:

```
{% for entry in nextEvent %}

    {% if entry.startDate > now %}
        {{ entry.startDate }}
        {% break %}
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```